# Accessing UNC path share folder WON'T let me

Tags: powershell, network-share

Thank you for taking the time to look into this and helping me out. I'm trying to access a share drive(s) that is password protected. So when I manually go to explorer and type \server\filepath\ it prompts this window. Which is great because I can enter my credential and then I can begin to use my script to copy-item.

[image]

SO, when I attempt to use `Set-Location -Path \\serverb\filepath` using Get-Credential domain\username it tells me that the path does not exist. When I do test-path \serverb\ it also says the path does not exist. But it will only exist when I manually type the folder share path in explorer, map a network drive or use the run command because it opens that prompt window (like the one from above). All I really want to do is use Powershell to `Copy-Item` even if I have to manually enter credentials. But it seems that the `Get-Credential` does not work at all when it comes to accessing protected network shares. The script below will work on \server\filepath because I have entered my credentials from the GUI prompt. But I cannot access use the same script on \serverb\filepath\file.txt because it doesn't see that the share exist. So now that I just manually went to it now the script works. But when I reboot my computer which cleared out the cache credentials I'm back to square one. Any thoughts?

[image]

```
Import-Module bitstransfer
$cred = Get-Credential
$sourcePath = "\\serverb\filepath\file.txt"
$destPath = "D:\some_folder"
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Credential $cred
```

Comment: You’ve either got typos in your question or you’re not actually using UNC paths - e.g. ```test-path \serverb\``` is looking for a folder called ```serverb``` in the root of the current drive *on your machine*, and ```$sourcePath = “serverb\…”’``` is looking for a folder called ```serverb``` in the current directory. And '```\server\filepath``` is a different path again. Could you confirm / correct the exact paths you’re using?

Comment: A UNC name is `\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. Here's what I have:
Scenario 1: using the script to access \\servername\TestShareName. The Credential pop up box appears. I enter my credential but then I get an error that the folder path does not exist.
Scenario 2: I manually go to \\servername\TestShareName using explorer or mapping the network share drive manually. I type the path manually and it prompts me the windows Security box. I enter my credential and this is how I normally get in. When I run my scripts it works.

Comment: Overall: I'm trying to either get the windows security dialog box to appear while running the script or the "Get-Credential" to work properly.

Comment: Try to establish a drive mapping first with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)  `-Credential`.

Comment: Thank you. I tested this and it works along with my script. I want to basically make this neater. Right now I just have this line of code on top of my bittransfer script. Do you have a way to rewrite this so that they are in one "{}" or function? Excuse me for not using the correct term. New-PSDrive -Name T -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\servername\TestShareName' -Credential (Get-Credential) -Persist

- The New-PsDrive -Credential will ask for credential. Then the script for bitstransfer will also ask for credential. So I'm having to type it twice. lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your feedback, it seems that access to the file share must be ensured first, which you can achieve by [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) with a suitable `-Credential` argument to map a (session-specific or persistent) *drive* (you needn't actually use a path based on that drive - a successful mapping will allow access even by UNC path).

```
Import-Module bitstransfer

# Prompt for credentials
$cred = Get-Credential

$sourcePath = '\\serverb\filepath\file.txt'
$destPath = 'D:\some_folder'

# Use the credentials to map a (temporary) drive named dummy:
# to the source file share, which will allow access to the latter, even 
# via UNC paths.
if (-not (Test-Path dummy:)) {
  New-PSDrive -Credential $cred dummy FileSystem \\serverb\filepath
}

Start-BitsTransfer -Credential $cred -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath
```

Comment: This is cleaner. I also had to add another variable to copy an additional file from the same network share directory so as of now thank you. You're a life saver.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @RunnerXdays; my pleasure.